# Executing function on click gives errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted my code to execute if function when I click the button, however no matter what I try it either does nothing or throws error at me.
Does anyone have some clue what could be wrong here?

```
import React from 'react';
export default class MojaKlasa extends React.Component {
  state = {showPass: 0};

  render() {
    function MojaFunkcja() {
      if (this.state.showPass === 0) {
        this.setState([showPass: 1])
      } else {
        this.setState([showPass: 0])
      }
    };
    return (
      <button className="przycisk" onClick={() => MojaFunkcja()}></button>
      <p>{this.state.showPass}</p>
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: Couple things.  You may need to bind your function in a constructor.  Also, you need to refer to your function with this.  Ala this.MojaFunkcja.  Also, you don't need the () after the function call.

Comment: *"throws error at me"* What's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make something like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { showPass: 0 };

  MojaFunkcja = () => {
    this.setState({ showPass: (this.state.showPass === 1) ? 0 : 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="przycisk" onClick={this.MojaFunkcja} />
        <p>{this.state.showPass}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few syntax errors and issues in your code...

import React from 'react';

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { showPass: 0 };

  MojaFunkcja = () => {
    this.setState({ showPass: this.state.showPass + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="przycisk" onClick={this.MojaFunkcja} />
        <p>{this.state.showPass}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted an if statement to switch showPass value to either 1 or 0 dependant on each click

Comment: I did not mean adding. I meant:
0 clicks: 0,
1 click: 1,
2 clicks: 0,
3 clicks: 1,
4 clicks: 0
and so on

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change showPass from int to boolean then your life will be easier

```
import React from 'react';
export default class MojaKlasa extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showPass: false
  };
  render() {
    function MojaFunkcja() {
     this.setState({ showPass: !this.state.showPass })
    };
    return (
        <>
      <button className="przycisk" onClick={MojaFunkcja}></button>
      <p> {this.state.showPass}</p>
        </>
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: The idea of using a boolean field instead of a numerical type is more robust, I do prefer using idea than mine.

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState([showPass: 0])` is not valid JavaScript syntax. You have to use `{}` instead of `[]` to create an object literal:

```
this.setState({showPass: 0})
```

Same for the other `setState` call.

You also cannot two elements after each other like this `return (<button></button> <a />);`. You either have to return an *array* of elements, or a single element:

```
return [ // <- array literal
   <button />
   <a />
];

// or

return (
  <span> // <- parent node
    <button />
    <a />
  </span>
);
```